# gradle not finding jar in mavenLocal repo

Tags: spring, maven, gradle, ivy

I have a dependency on spring-beans;4.0.0.RELEASE, which I installed into my mavenLocal cache using

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Users/jric/Downloads/spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar -DpomFile=/Users/jric/Downloads/spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.pom`,

but gradle-1.11 is failing to find the dependency, without much explanation.  I did find this relevant-looking stack trace:

```
11:26:35.432 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver] Discarding resolve failure.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenLocalResolver.isOrphanedPom(MavenLocalResolver.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenLocalResolver.findMetaDataArtifact(MavenLocalResolver.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:165)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.getDependency(MavenResolver.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LocalModuleVersionRepository.getLocalDependency(LocalModuleVersionRepository.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.CachedRepository.getLocalDependency(CachedRepository.java:67)
```

Here's some more possibly-relevant data:

```
SCML-JRichardson:share jric$ ls /Users/jric/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/
4.0.0.RELEASE           maven-metadata-local.xml
SCML-JRichardson:share jric$ cat /Users/jric/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata-local.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <release>4.0.0.RELEASE</release>
    <versions>
      <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20150307021047</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
SCML-JRichardson:share jric$ ls /Users/jric/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.0.RELEASE/
_maven.repositories     spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar  spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.pom
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gradle has a special statement to look in the local Maven repository: mavenLocal(). Make sure you call it in the global repositories section:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()  // <- Here
    mavenCentral()
}
```

If it doesn't work, make sure you didn't add it inadvertently in the buildscript section. That would add the dependency to your build environment instead of your code, which is typically not what you want.

```
buildscript {            // <- Probably not what you mean
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: The `buildscript` section got me, thanks for the point!

Comment: this is what fixed mine, i removed the mavenLocal() from inside the buildscript/repositories and instead placed it on another allprojects/repositories script within my build gradle. :)